# Store pivot table values on creation in Laravel with Ajax input

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, relationship

I'm learning Laravel by creating a recipe website.

The idea is a user creates a recipe which includes a title, description and number of portions (and tags), and then is directed to a new view in which they add the ingredients.

I've got this working, and the user can successfully create the recipe and the ingredients, which are being written to their respective tables, but I'm unable to attach/sync them.

**Relevant parts of the models:**

**Recipe Model:**

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
  public function ingredients(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ingredient', 'recipe_ingredients');
  }
}
```

**Ingredient Model:**

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{

  public function recipe(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe', 'recipe_ingredients');
  }
}
```

**Ingredients Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255'
  ]);

  $ingredient = new Ingredient;
  $ingredient->name = $request->name;
  $ingredient->save();

  $recipe = Recipe::find($request->id);

  $recipe->ingredients()->attach($recipe_id);

  $data = [
    'success' => true,
    'message'=> 'Your AJAX processed correctly',
    'name' => $ingredient->name,
    'recipe' => $recipe
  ] ;

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

If I remove the `$recipe->ingredients()->attach($recipe_id);` the ingredients save to the ingredients table, but I can't get the `recipe_id` and `ingredient_id` to save in the `recipe_ingredients` table`.

I *think* I'm using the attach wrong, but I could be wrong.

**Note:**
Not that I think it makes any difference, but I'm submitting the data via Ajax.

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var name = $("#ingredientName").val();
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $.ajax({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
      type: "post",
      data: "name="+name,
      dataType:'json',
      url: "{{ route('ingredients.store', ['id' => $recipe->id]) }}",
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-success my-0">'+data.name+' added</div>');
        $("#msg").toggleClass("invisible")
        $("#msg").fadeOut(2000);
        $("#ingredientsTable").append('<tr><td scope="col" class="align-middle">'+data.name+'</td></tr>');
      }
    });
  })
})
```

**Revised Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255'
  ]);

  $ingredient = new Ingredient;
  $ingredient->name = $request->name;
  $ingredient->save();

  $recipe = Recipe::find($request->id);
  $recipe->ingredients()->attach($ingredient->id);

  $data = [
    'success' => true,
    'message'=> 'Your AJAX processed correctly',
    'name' => $ingredient->name,
    'recipe' => $recipe
  ] ;

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

**Table migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recipe_ingredients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('recipe_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('recipe_id')->references('id')->on('recipes');

        $table->integer('ingredient_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ingredient_id')->references('id')->on('ingredients');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong ID when trying to attach the Ingredient to the Recipe:

```
$ingredient = new Ingredient;
$ingredient->name = $request->name;
$ingredient->save();

$recipe = Recipe::find($request->id);
$recipe->ingredients()->attach($recipe_id);
```

In the last line, you already have the Recipe, so passing `$recipe_id` (which I actually don't see defined anywhere) is not the correct logic.

What you need to do is pass the Ingredient you want to attach:

```
$recipe->ingredients()->attach($ingredient->id);
```

That should correctly set the relationship.

Comment: I've changed it to the above, and it still fails to save. Revised OP with the updated controller. It still saves the ingredients, but doesn't save the relationship.

Comment: your relationship on the `Ingredient` Model is incorrect, i've edited my answer to show you what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

As shown by the example here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

You should be attaching the `ingredients` instead of the recipe:

`$recipe->ingredients()->attach($ingredient_id);`

-- **edit** --

You also have your `Ingredient` model as:

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{
  public function ingredient(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Recipe', 'recipe_ingredients');
  }
}
```

However, you should have this instead:

```
public function recipes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Recipe', 'recipe_ingredients');
}
```

Comment: I pasted in the wrong model. Have updated OP with the correct model.

Answer (score 0):

After making lots of little tweaks and changes, the following finally worked for me:

**Recipe /model:**

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
  public function ingredients(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ingredient', 'recipe_ingredients', 'recipe_id', 'ingredient_id');
  }
```

**Ingredient Model:**

```
class Ingredient extends Model
{
    public function recipes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Recipe', 'recipe_ingredients', 'ingredient_id', 'recipe_id');
}
```

**IngredientsController@Store: **

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255'
  ]);

  $ingredient = new Ingredient;
  $ingredient->name = $request->name;
  $ingredient->save();

  $recipe = Recipe::find($request->id);
  $ingredient->recipes()->attach($recipe->id);

  $data = [
    'success' => true,
    'message'=> 'Your AJAX processed correctly',
    'name' => $ingredient->name,
    'recipe' => $recipe
  ] ;

    return response()->json($data);
}
```